# Differentiable proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $$f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$$
 be differentiable at $x_0\in (a,b)$. Prove that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{xf(x_0)-x_0f(x)}{x-x_0}=f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0)\,.$$
Is this as simple as multiplying by a conjugate and reducing? I tried but I got lost in the simplifying.

Comment: **Hint:** Write $xf(x_0)-x_0f(x)=xf(x_0)-x_0f(x_0)+x_0f(x_0)-x_0f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{xf(x_0)-x_0f(x)}{x-x_0} &= 
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{xf(x_0) - x_0f(x_0) + x_0f(x_0)-x_0f(x)}{x-x_0}\\
&= f(x_0)\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x - x_0}{x-x_0}  + \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x_0f(x_0)-x_0f(x)}{x-x_0}\\
&= f(x_0) - x_0\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\\
&= f(x_0) - x_0f^\prime(x_0).
\end{align*}
It's also helpful to remember that this type of "addition/substraction" trick is useful when dealing with such problems!

Comment: ohhhhhh you added 0 basically and used it to separate the equations so that they would simplify more easily

Comment: @JJBurt Exactly! Hope this helped! Again, a very useful trick.